# iterate a hash of array in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this hash that got a array in it:

```
{
  "id": "0001001",
  "name": "Bob Fisher",
  "work": [
    {
      "employer": {
        "id": "6883542487",
        "name": "Marvel"
      },
      "location": {
        "id": "108081209214649",
        "name": "Las Vegas, Nevada"
      },
      "position": {
        "id": "148835345140954",
        "name": "Cirkusdirektör"
      },
      "description": "API testing",
      "start_date": "2012-01",
      "end_date": "2013-01"
    },
    {
      "employer": {
        "id": "11648563484",
        "name": "DC Comics"
      },
      "location": {
        "id": "108424279189115",
        "name": "New York, New York"
      },
      "position": {
        "id": "178387758878908",
        "name": "Dykare"
      },
      "description": "Api testing",
      "start_date": "2010-02",
      "end_date": "2011-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to I iterate every employer values in ruby? So I get a output like this:

```
Employer name: Marvel
Location name: Las Vegas, Nevada
Position: Cirkusdirektör
Description: Api testing
Start-date: 2012-01
End-date: 2013-01

Employer name: DC Comics
Location name: New York, New 
Position: Cirkusdirektör
Description: Api testing
Start-date: 2012-01
End-date: 2011-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h = {
  "id"=> "0001001",
  "name"=> "Bob Fisher",
  "work"=> [
    {
      "employer"=> {
        "id"=> "6883542487",
        "name"=> "Marvel"
      },
      "location"=> {
        "id"=> "108081209214649",
        "name"=> "Las Vegas, Nevada"
      },
      "position"=> {
        "id"=> "148835345140954",
        "name"=> "Cirkusdirektör"
      },
      "description"=> "API testing",
      "start_date"=> "2012-01",
      "end_date"=> "2013-01"
    },
    {
      "employer"=> {
        "id"=> "11648563484",
        "name"=> "DC Comics"
      },
      "location"=> {
        "id"=> "108424279189115",
        "name"=> "New York, New York"
      },
      "position"=> {
        "id"=> "178387758878908",
        "name"=> "Dykare"
      },
      "description"=> "Api testing",
      "start_date"=> "2010-02",
      "end_date"=> "2011-01"
    }
  ]
}

h.values.last.each do |x| 

  puts "---------------------------------------"
  puts "Employer name:- #{x['employer']['name']}"
  puts "Location name:- #{x['location']['name']}"
  puts "Position:- #{x['position']['name']}"
  puts "Description:- #{x['description']}"
  puts "Start-date:- #{x['start_date']}"
  puts "End-date: #{x['end_date']}"
  puts "---------------------------------------"

end
```

*Output:*

```
---------------------------------------
Employer name:- Marvel
Location name:- Las Vegas, Nevada
Position:- Cirkusdirektör
Description:- API testing
Start-date:- 2012-01
End-date: 2013-01
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Employer name:- DC Comics
Location name:- New York, New York
Position:- Dykare
Description:- Api testing
Start-date:- 2010-02
End-date: 2011-01
---------------------------------------
```

*Code Breaking:*

```
h.values.last.each do |x|
 p x
end
```

*Output:*

```
{"employer"=>{"id"=>"6883542487", "name"=>"Marvel"}, "location"=>{"id"=>"108081209214649", "name"=>"Las Vegas, Nevada"}, "position"=>{"id"=>"148835345140954", "name"=>"Cirkusdirekt\u00F6r"}, "description"=>"API testing", "start_date"=>"2012-01", "end_date"=>"2013-01"}

{"employer"=>{"id"=>"11648563484", "name"=>"DC Comics"}, "location"=>{"id"=>"108424279189115", "name"=>"New York, New York"}, "position"=>{"id"=>"178387758878908", "name"=>"Dykare"}, "description"=>"Api testing", "start_date"=>"2010-02", "end_date"=>"2011-01"}
```

Comment: can you please explain the loop part, what happens there

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake tell me now which part confused you, I just have broken the loop.

Comment: That was not what I meant, but that dosent matter now. I check the ruby api. thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a little risky since `"work"` could not always be the last element? After all `Hash`es in Ruby are not ordered..

Comment: @Itehnological `SO` is not for complete solution,It gives you hints,it helps you to go one step above,by providing ideas. Now I tried the same as per the OP's post. Now if the situation come as you said, OP should manage that,if he understood this code. Because that will not be a big challenge. Here we never assume, what have been asked,we answer that only.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as that:

```
data['work'].each do |entry|
  puts entry['employer']['name']
  puts entry['location']['name']
  puts entry['position']['name']
  puts entry['description']
  puts entry['start_date']
  puts entry['end_date']
end
```

Comment: That loops once and not twice. So I only get the first part and not the second.

Comment: Is your data JSON and do you need to parse it?

Comment: Its data from facebook graph and its not JSON